# ActiveRecord: как обеспечить записи время жизни?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Хочу написать на Ruby on Rails веб сайт с самоудаляющимися сообщениями, есть 2 варианта:

1. удалить после просмотра
2. удалить через заданое время

С первым понятно.
Для второго варианта нужен `created_at` но где разместить саму проверку и удаление?

Comment: Господа закрывашки, видимо, немножко не в курсе, что Rails это веб-фреймворк, типично исполняющий код в рамках циклов запрос-ответ. Вопрос же о том, как обрабатывать события, происходящие **вне** этих циклов. В контексте Rails вопрос очень даже конкретен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вас интересует по большей части не то, чтобы сообщения **удалялись**, когда истекают, а чтобы они **не показывались**.

Если вы хотите сделать настраиваемое время жизни, лучше создать поле `expires_at`, где указать, с какого момента сообщение подлежит удалению.

А потом сделать скоуп такого вида:

```
scope :actual, -> { where("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > expires_at") }
```

Используйте этот скоуп при операциях чтения, и с точки зрения пользователей будет похоже, будто истекшие сообщения удаляются. А **именно удалять** их можно, сделав задачу, запускающуюся через фиксированные промежутки времени, любым удобным вам способом: крон, внешний планировщик, фоновая очередь с расписанием, что хотите.

Поскольку запросы к этому полю будут почти постоянно, убедитесь, что в базе есть необходимые индексы.

---

Это, правда, непрямое решение. Более прямым решением было бы использование хранилища данных, поддерживающего время жизни внутри себя. Но насколько я знаю, ActiveRecord не поддерживает ни одного такого. Да и плюсы от такого решения невелики.

Comment: если `expires_at` - дата удаления то так: `scope :actual, -> { where("expires_at > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP") }`

Comment: @Escobar верно! Поменял их местами, сделав порядок в сравнении совпадающим с ожидаемым порядком следования (чтобы, грубо, визуально видеть, что должно быть после чего, просто из порядка следования).